# DLL Decompilation

Tags: .net, dll, decompiling, reflector

I'm trying to decompile a dll with the tool called Reflector, but it shows only the definitions, not the complete code. What is the reason? How can I decompile it completely?

Regards

Comment: Provide a screenshot. Have no idea what you mean.

Comment: ok guys, sorry. This is the point I learned what extern means. The methods are implemented somewhere else. Now I'm trying to understand the rest. An example of the decompiled code was:          [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), TypeLibFunc((short) 0x40), DispId(0x2f)]
        public virtual extern void _DoCommand([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string Verb, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string PlugInKey = "");

Comment: @Saha: That means it's a mixed mode assembly, there is no .NET code (MSIL) in the function you're asking about, only native machine code wrapped in .NET metadata.  Reflector won't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a mixed-mode DLL?  Have you expanded a method to see its decompiled source?

You might find the [`FileDisassembler`](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plugin to be helpful (not sure if this is the most recent version).

Answer (score 1):

right click on an assembly, namespace, class, or member and pick "disassemble" from the context menu.  or as a shortcut, press the spacebar

Comment: @sahs define "doesn't help"? what happens? what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Open Reflector

Right click on the dll you want to extract

click Export

Give c:\YourDirectoryName.

You will have your extracted code in c:\YourDirectoryName

Answer (score 0):

To see the code in reflector, you must navigate *to a method*. If you are looking at a *type*, then yes - it will only show you definitions, even when disassembled (although there is sometimes an "Expand Methods" button that can be helpful).

If it still doesn't work, even when looking at a method, then the dll is most likely obfuscated or not compiled from code (direct IL can do things that are hard to map back to most languages).

Comment: You'd still be able to view it as MSIL.  Whereas what he has is a mixed-mode assembly containing native code and .NET metadata, but not MSIL.  There's nothing to decompile.  C++/CLI is the most common way of creating such assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

In Reflector, drill down the treeview on the left to find the type whose code you want to view. Once you've found it, click on it to select it and press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. You'll then see the method declarations to the right. Scroll down to the very bottom of that view, and click the green "Expand Methods" hyperlink.

Alternatively, expand that type in the treeview, select an individual method, and then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Comment: OT: So how do you make those pretty keys?

Comment: @leppie: `<kbd>Key name here</kbd>`